# Logging in a text file iPhone

Tags: iphone, file, nsdata, text-files, save

I have a score system and I would like to log *all* scores in a text file separated by line breaks. Here is my current save code:

```
NSData *dataToWrite = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"String to write ID:%i \n",random] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];

 // Write the file
 [dataToWrite writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

When retrieving this data, I only see the latest save. How do I make it so it saves all in a list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[dataToWrite writeToFile:path atomically:YES];` overwrites the file at that location, replacing whatever is there with the contents of `dataToWrite`.

You can likely use `NSFileHandle`'s `fileHandleForWritingAtPath:` and then call `seekToEndOfFile` to append to said file.

---

> Do you have an example?

Try something like:

```
NSFileHandle *f = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: p];
[f seekToEndOfFile];
[f writeData: d];
[f close];
```

All typed into SO;  the compiler/runtime might differ with my opinions of correctness.

Comment: Works! Thank you. How would I delete the contents of the file?

Comment: `dataToWrite = @""; [dataToWrite writeToFile:path atomically:YES];`

Comment: If you're satisfied with this answer, you should accept it by clicking the ✔ next to the answer. This rewards the author of the answer.