# Is there a more efficient way to append a log to a log file than this?

Tags: ios, foundation

I don't like what I have written here. The entire contents of the log file is pulled into memory, and I was wondering if there is a way to append to whatever is there, without pulling it out.

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Log"];
NSMutableString *content = [@"" mutableCopy];
NSMutableString *existing = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] mutableCopy];
[content appendString:existing];
[content appendString:@"\n"];
[content appendString:[user logDetails]];
[[content copy] writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging in a text file iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653012/logging-in-a-text-file-iphone)

Comment: (`seekToEndOfFile` is your friend)

Answer (score 0):

That code is *very* inefficient, but this is because file manipulation in general is poor when using the Foundation classes.

I would recommend using the C-API functions `fopen()`, `fprintf()`, etc instead.  Simply write the UTF-8 strings from `NSString` objects and logging will be much quicker and won't endanger the memory footprint of the app.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything very inefficient in seeking to the end of file and writing one `NSData` object. The code is inefficient because he is loading and saving the entire file, not because he is using wrong functions to do it.

Comment: @Amadan Sure, but `NSFileHandle` is still "poor" IMO, given it can use exceptions to signal error.  However it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to write custom stuff to the end of a file, then yes, see the comments from @Amadan.  If you mean that you want a proper logging system, with log rotation and asynchronous logging and all sorts of other things, then check out https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.  More love has gone into that than you will ever dream of investing yourself.

Ignore @trojanfoe's answer -- you're just making more work for yourself if you drop to the C APIs, for very little gain.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my `FileSystem` class:

```
+ (BOOL)appendData:(NSData *)_data toFile:(NSString *)_path
{
    if( !_path || !_data )
        return NO;

    // TODO : check before for file existence

    // open for binary append
    FILE *_file = fopen([_path UTF8String], "ab"); 

    if( !_file )
        return NO;

    size_t _nbObjToWrite = [_data length];
    size_t _nbObjWritten = fwrite([_data bytes], 1, _nbObjToWrite, _file); // write [_data length] objectq of length 1 from [_data bytes] buffer in _file

    if( _nbObjWritten != _nbObjToWrite ) {
        fclose( _file );
        return NO;
    }

    fclose( _file ); // will automatically flush the stream

    return YES;
}
```

And then, you can call:

```
[MyClass appendData:[<myLogStringToAdd> dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] toFile:@"<pathToMyFile>"];
```

Comment: Why not keep the file open all the time?

Comment: To keep resources available and be sure the content is written to the file. If the app must write to the file constantly, that's another story. If it must write once every few seconds, I prefer closing the file.

Comment: You are saving the wrong resources; it takes resources to open and close files.

Comment: The underlying BSD system has a max number of open files at one time, and I already cross this limit in another project a few years ago. I'm now very careful and conservative, especially because there are a lot of other process running at the same time.

Comment: Well we are talking about a logging function here, so I assume there will be many calls to it.  The only time I've ever reached the maximum file descriptors is when I've has a file handle leak.

Comment: I try to make as little assumptions as possible. If the OP need a more efficient solution, he will tell us.